# Laravel PostgreSQL Connection SSL

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, security, ssl

What is the best way, or the way to connect from Laravel to Postgresql using SSL?

My .env

`DB_CONNECTION=pgsql`

`DB_HOST=10.124.0.3`

`DB_PORT=35536`

`DB_DATABASE=laravel`

`DB_USERNAME=username`

`DB_PASSWORD=password`

`DB_SSLMODE=require`

`DB_SSLCERT=/var/lib/pgsql/15/data/server.crt`

`DB_SSLKEY=/var/lib/pgsql/15/data/server.key`

`DB_SSLROOTCERT=/var/lib/pgsql/15/data/root.crt`

or where is the documentation.

my env is correct?

Regards.

what is the correct way to connect to postgresql with laravel with ssl connection

Comment: Maybe don't post real usernames and passwords on a public site...

Answer (score -1):

Though it is not right to paste the actual credentials on a public site, the configurations look fine and should work as is.